# IPv4 Forwarding (NAT) only works after toggling IPv4 forwarding to off then on

Tags: debian, routing, nat, ufw, proxmox

This literally makes no sense and I'm stumped about why this is happening, but hear me out.

Currently I'm using Proxmox 6 (Debian) and I created a NAT so VMs/LXC containers can communicate between them + having internet connectivity to the outside world. I'm also using `ufw` for firewall stuff.

I was able to create the NAT connection fine, VMs can communicate between them, great!

...but internet connectivity doesn't work *at all*, why? I have no idea, but I found out that if I do this...

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

The issue is *magically* fixed. Yes, `ip_forward` is enabled on UFW's config

```
#
# Configuration file for setting network variables. Please note these settings
# override /etc/sysctl.conf and /etc/sysctl.d. If you prefer to use
# /etc/sysctl.conf, please adjust IPT_SYSCTL in /etc/default/ufw. See
# Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt in the kernel source code for more
# information.
#

# Uncomment this to allow this host to route packets between interfaces
net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
net/ipv6/conf/default/forwarding=1
net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding=1
```

And if I reboot the machine and do `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, the result is `1`, but internet connectivity is broken until I toggle it on and off!

So I'm stumped, I have no idea why this is happen and while there is a dirty workaround (toggling it off and on) I wanted to know if there is a *correctly* to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in `ifupdown2`, `dhcp` interfaces are not being IPv4 forwarded by default, even if you set the forwarding in `sysctl.conf`

Here's a thread where spirit found out about this bug: https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/reloading-ifupdown2-breaks-internet-connectivity-within-containers-vms-until-toggling-ip-forward.78933/#post-349753

As a workaround, you can add `ip-forward 1` to the `/etc/network/interfaces` or you can toggle IPv4 forwarding manually (just like what I did in the question)

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt) of `ip_forward` configuration parameter says:

> This variable is special, its change resets all configuration
> parameters to their default state (RFC1122 for hosts, RFC1812
> for routers)

So, the simplest hypothesis is that something else (of `sysctl`) is misconfigured and the problem disappears only when it is reset to default.

Comment: Something that I forgot to mention in the question (that I found out a few hours later) is that uninstalling the `ifupdown2` package (required by Proxmox if you want to do network updates without rebooting) *does* fix the issue.

Comment: @MrPowerGamerBR So, could you post a self answer for a better visibility for otherrs?

Comment: Not yet, what I did wasn't a proper fix. `ifupdown2` *should* technically work correctly, if it doesn't, then it would be a bug in the package.

Also because I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on my two tests VMs with Proxmox in a cluster, only on my dedicated server. So I'm trying to figure out how to *really* fix the issue instead of putting a workaround that shouldn't be needed here.

Comment: Found the issue! tl;dr: Bug in `ifupdown2` with `dhcp` interfaces: https://serverfault.com/a/1042562/554141

Comment: @MrPowerGamerBR Good find, nice!